# Navigate from one view to another using UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an application with 2 views . In the first one I have a button which when I clicked the user should go to the second view. I tried what is explained before here from Karoley , but it does not work . When I click the button nothing happened?

Here is the code of my action :

```
-(IBAction)gotoSecondPage:(id) sender{
    NSLog(@"In gotoSecondPage");

        LeoActionViewController *aSecondPageController =
        [[LeoActionViewController  alloc] 
         initWithNibName:@"LeoActionViewController" 
         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondPageController animated:YES];
}
```

LeoActionViewCOntroller is a controler for a second view.
It just do not switch to a second view. I do not know why

Comment: can you post your code. I've attempted an answer, but its pretty difficult without seeing what you're talking about.

Comment: By 2 views you mean 2 UIViewController subclasses? Who is Karoley, and what exactly have you tried?

Comment: Yes 2 UIViewCOntroller classes I mean. Karoley is one person in the forum that propose the code.

Comment: Do `self` have a navigationController?

Comment: Ok. When you create a UINavigationController instance and push to him viewcontroller with your first view?

Comment: that code looks fine... erm - is it NSLogging? is the function definitely getting run? Are there any errors or crashes? The only thing I can think is that the function isn't getting run at all.

Comment: It run and I see the log info into the log from NSLog. I just can not go to the second view. Nothing happened.

Comment: beryllium: Yes that right. I do this in my appdelegate method like this: Login *aFirstPageViewController = [[Login alloc]
            initWithNibName:@"Login"
            bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 self.firstPageViewController = aFirstPageViewController;
 
 [aFirstPageViewController release];
 [window addSubview:[firstPageViewController view]];

Comment: Thomas: addSubview method is method of UIWindow not UIViewController class I can not use it . I use this in my appdelegate to load the first view in application window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure in what capacity you want to switch views.

What immediately comes to mind is that you want a [Navigation Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is an object that lets you put view controllers on a stack and push and pop them to show and hide them. It creates a navigation pathway through your app and is easy to use. It also facilitates the 'standard' navigation bar which is found in many iphone apps.

If you just want to change one view for another view you can do many things including hiding and showing different views using `setHidden:(bool)hidden`. Otherwise you can use `addSubview:(UIView *)view` and `removeFromSuperview` to add and remove views completely from the superview.

Comment: Yes I just want to change one view for another when the button is clicked.

Comment: It worked but with this code: LoginAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [delegate.window addSubview:[aSecondPageController view]];

Comment: right - then you don't have a navigation controller set up. You need to set up a navigation controller and use the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I put code your problem this will help you.  First of all, you declare method and open .xib file and then connect to that button with selected touchupinside connection.

In the .h file:

```
- (IBAction)gotoSecondPage:(id) sender;
```

In the .m file:

```
 - (IBAction)gotoSecondPage:(id) sender
    {
        NSLog(@"In gotoSecondPage");

        LeoActionViewController *aSecondPageController = 
            [[LeoActionViewController  alloc] 
            initWithNibName:@"LeoActionViewController" 
            bundle:nil];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondPageController animated:YES];

     [aSecondPageController release];
    }
```